# Converting numbers from text file to Python numbers

Tags: python

I want read a text file list of comma-separated numbers in each line, such as:

```
2,1,3
3,1,3
2,9
```

and want to convert it to a list of lists. My current function looks like this:

```py
def nested_int_list_from_file(file):
    f = open(file)
    xs = []
    for line in f :
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        else:
            x = line.strip().split(', ')
            line = [(i) for i in x]
            xs.append(line)
    return xs
```

Currently, the numbers are in the output are strings:

```py
[['2', '1', '3'], ['3', '1', '3'], ['2', '9']]
```

But I want them to be numbers instead:

```py
[[2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 3], [2, 9]]
```

How do I need to change my function to do that?

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I would say from the title, function name, and example outputs the question is obvious, no?

Answer (score 2):

Modify this line

```
line = [int(i) for i in x]
```

You should also be aware that python comes with [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) that can already read comma delimited text files. So does [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html?highlight=genfromtxt#numpy.genfromtxt) if you want to read into a 2D array for linear algebra purposes.